# Article Rich Snippet with JSON-LD and PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, rich-snippets, json-ld

I am trying to create a JSON-LD data block which uses PHP from WordPress to create rich snippets for Google and I've run into a little problem, for the `publisher` property.

I need it in the following format (this is from Google):

```
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Example Publisher",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://example.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
$schema["Publisher"] = array(
    "@type" => "Organization", 
    "name" => "Company Name",
    "@type" => "ImageObject", 
    "url" => "logo url goes here", // Get Image URL
    "height" => 159, // Height
    "width" => 500, // Width
    );
```

But this is not picking up correctly, I believe this is because I need to add an additional inside the Publisher attribute for the logo itself.

Just wondering if anyone had any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting array inside array like this:

```
$schema["Publisher"] = array(
    "@type" => "Organization", 
    "name" => "Company Name",
    "logo" => array(
        "@type" => "ImageObject", 
        "url" => "logo url goes here", // Get Image URL
        "height" => 159, // Height
        "width" => 500, // Width
    )
);
```